# iOS: Access Storyboard TabBar ViewController from another Class

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have the following problem:
I created a iOS 5 SDK application with Storyboard that contains a TabBar and three ViewControllers.
From another Class (Receiver.m) I want to access a UI Label on e.g. ThirdViewController.m which is one of the thee ViewControllers of the TabBar.

In ThirdViewController.h i got

```
@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController {
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textlabel1;
@end
```

and in ThirdViewController.h:

```
@implementation ThirdViewController
@synthesize textlabel1;
...
```

This seems OK, since i can set the label properties from within the ThirdViewController instance.
Now to get access from within Receiver.m I use:

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   ThirdViewController *myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];
   myVC.textlabel1.text = @"Hello";
```

This does not work. I do not want to create a new instance of ThirdViewController but access the existing one to update just the UILabel. My Storyboard in Project Navigator is default named MainStoryboard.storyboard .
Am I doing something wrong here with getting the ThirdViewController classes instance?

The error says:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x190590>) doesn't contain a view controller with 
identifier 'ThirdViewController''
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboard doesn't give you a way to access the already presented version of a view controller - as you've found, the method you are using creates a new instance.

I would question the structure of your code if you are expecting an external object to update a specific label belonging to a view controller. This is not a typical design pattern as it makes a tight dependency between the two objects.  Usually you would set your view controller to be the delegate of your Receiver object (if it is created by that view controller), or your receiver object would send a notification that your third view controller is listening for.

Comment: Ok, that is what I feared. So is there any other way (I found something like AppDelegate.window.ThirdViewController which does not work either) to somehow get the ThirdViewController instance over the ViewController 'hierarchy'? Thanks for your recommendation, I am aware of the fact that it is not good style, the code will change but since the application logic is missing I am trying to access the ViewController directly that way.

Comment: You'd have to get the tab bar controller (the root view controller of app delegate.window) then get your third view controller from the viewcontrollers array of the tab bar controller.

Comment: `AppDelegate.window.UINavigationController.ThirdViewController` does not get me there. Did anyone did this before and is willing to share some code snippets? I would appreciate that. Otherwise I will have to change some of the code's structure.

Comment: It would be more like `[appdelegate.window.rootViewController.viewcontrollers objectAtIndex:2]` but you'd probably need some casting to prevent compiler errors. It's the wrong approach, though, you should use delegates or notification as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't pay attention to this thread for a while, but just for those who are interested how it works I do post this, though I won't use this in my code (thanks comments from @jrturton above)

```
// Bad style:
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *vcs = appDelegate.window.rootViewController.childViewControllers;   
YourFirstViewController *fvc  = [vcs objectAtIndex:0];
YourSecondViewController *svc = [vcs objectAtIndex:1];
```

I will therefore mark jrturton's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[ZCDev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056692/zcdev) answer didn't work for me. This worked:

```
let tabBarViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController as!   UITabBarController
```

Safer option:

```
if let tabBarViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    // access your tab bar controller here.
}
```

Swift 3, Xcode 8, iOS 10